Removing Seaborn Boxplot scaling y axis unnecessarily
I am generating a number of boxplots using Seaborn.
Most are generating fine with the correct linear y-axis scale, but some have a value (such as 1e-7+7.0334e-1) on the top left corner of the plot that I believe to be a scaler. This makes the y-axis labels look really wrong (showing ~5.8 instead of ~0.7).
Is there a way I can force the y-axis ticks to show using standard values instead of this scaling factor?
all_arr = []
for run in range(0, 27, 1):
    #access data to plot (27 plots across, 27 datapoints in each)
    recordname1 = str(dataset.iloc[atira, 1]) + " run:" + str(run) + "clonemin.csv"
    my_plot_data1 = genfromtxt(recordname1, delimiter=',')
    data1 = my_plot_data1[5, :]
    #print stats that are being plotted
    print(min(data1), np.quantile(data1, 0.25), np.median(data1), np.quantile(data1, 0.75), max(data1))
    #Combine data into list of arrays
    all_arr.append(data1)
#Plot data
sns.boxplot(data=all_arr)
#Add label
plt.xlabel('Runs (velocity profiles)')
#Save and display plots
recordname2 = str(dataset.iloc[atira, 1])
path1 = recordname2 + "Min_SemiMajAxis_Boxplot.png"
plt.savefig(path1)
plt.show()

